# In Python + Pylons, simple way to copy uploaded file to disk

Tags: python, pylons

How can I copy a posted file to disk?

Can I do something like:

```
file = '/uploaded_files/test.txt'
shutil.copy2(request.POST['file'],file)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do something like this:

```
tempfile = request.POST['file']
file_path = 'uploaded_files/' + tempfile.filename # for the original filename
permanent_file = open( file_path, 'wb')
shutil.copyfileobj(tempfile.file, permanent_file)
```